# Sitecore XM Cloud local setup error with Node.js

Tags: xm-cloud, setup

I am preparing am XM Cloud project for local development with `Node.js`. On completion of the setup I am getting the below error:

```
error - FetchError: request to https://edge.sitecorecloud.io/api/graphql/v1 failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700:91b3:c4eb:e83b:421:f8c7:3c32:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\HeadlessDemo\XMCloudDemo\src\sxastarter\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\node-fetch\index.js:1:65756)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  page: '/en/_site_XMCloudDemo'
}
```

I can fetch data from GraphQL API using parameter:

> https://edge.sitecorecloud.io/api/graphql/ide

I follow the below URL to setup my local environment:

> https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/walkthrough--connecting-the-next-js-application-directly-to-the-experience-edge-endpoint.html

Please help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got help from Sitecore Slack Headless group and as suggested I run
`npm ci` command on the Front-end app root directory. That resolved my initial problem.
Initially I did `npm install` instead of `npm ci`.

Then I encountered bellow error-
[image]

As I am doing local setup and I don't need CDP, so I just disabled CDP from `CdpPageView` in the `src\Scripts.tsx` file as suggested in different blogs and YouTube videos.

Answer (score 0):

Likely this happens because the port 443 is blocked. Please check and ensure that the port is enabled.

If IIS is running by default then simply stop it by executing `iisreset /stop` in `cmd` to release the required ports for the web apps and Solr.

Comment: Thanks, Kate, for the suggestion, but 443 is enabled. I got a solution of the problem and posted that.